# Chromium's XSS auditor refused to execute a script

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

This is a message from the Chrome Inspector:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in
>   `http://localhost/Disposable Working NOTAS.php`
>   because its source code was found within the request.
>   The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither
>   an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

... I have a couple dozen websites sitting on localhost on my notebook which I use for a big part of my workflow, and in the last couple days, after an updated Chrome changed something, pretty much all the websites' textareas' content is not being saved to file anymore.

The code which was saving edits I made, is uniformly broken; I enter new text, click
on *save* and my browser, instead of executing the file~writing subroutines in the script
for the webpage I am working in, simply opens a new blank page.  If I then hit the back
button, the textarea still shows the freshly added content, but in the file, no changes
are being appended.

Comment: What do you save in those textareas? Are they used as HTML editors? If you enter Javascript code in the textarea, and your server returns that code, it will trigger the XSS protection auditor.

Comment: Ah, right... that IS a better title for the question  ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you'd like to tell Chrome to disable its XSS protection, you can send an `X-XSS-Protection` header with a value of `0`. Since you appear to be using PHP, you'd add this somewhere where it'll always be executed before any content has been output:

```php
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

Comment: That placed in the < Head > inside the proper php tags, seems to have completely fixed the issue.  Opera, Safari, Firefox were all fine, it was ONLY Chrome giving my scripts guff, and only after one of Google's auto version~updates, it broke something and this fixes it.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Ideally it should be placed before any html output is printed, not inside the <head> tag.  Otherwise it will fail on servers where php's output buffering is disabled or set to a small value.

Comment: @JoeCoder Ah, noted.  Appreciate that detail.

Comment: what about .net(aspx pages)

Comment: @Vishal: I'm not very familiar with them, but judging from the documentation, I think `Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "0");` would do the trick, assuming `Response` is an `HttpResponse`.

Comment: This header can be sent from the web server itself; e.g., in apache, you can add this line to the `httpd.conf` for the site that needs it:
`Header set X-XSS-Protection 0`

Answer (score 17):

If you are getting blocked by XSS Auditor, you should check whether your code has a XSS vulnerability or not before simply disabling it.

If you're getting blocked by XSS Auditor, there's a decent chance you have a XSS vulnerability and just didn't realize it.  If you simply disable the XSS Auditor, you will remain vulnerable: it's treating the symptoms, rather than the underlying illness (the root cause).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered exactly the same issue when I was studying XSS recently. And below screenshot shows a PHP way to bypass Chrome XSS Auditor.

Just add -- header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");

[image]

Comment: NB: if you get a "Headers already sent" error, place the PHP snippet at the top of the document or turn on output buffering.