# How add form tag to wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, xss

I want add form tag to wordpress page (dashboard -> pages -> add page)

```
<form action="demo_form.php" method="get">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="add links..."></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

but i get this error in console

```
The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://localhost/dbwp/?page_id=2310&preview=true&preview_id=2310&preview_nonce=0e7d5307ee' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.
```

how i can solve it?

Comment: This is a Chrome issues and not a Wordpress issue. See this answer for the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017013/325521

Comment: Is necessary to resolve it? if yes and i add `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");` no security issue occurred?

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying. Did you add the header and the issue went away? Or is it still there? Or are you concerned about security issue?

Comment: problem solved after add `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");` but my question: is my site protected from xss attack after adding `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");`?