# How to work around Chrome's XSS auditor false positive with Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, xss, content-security-policy

There exists a known [false positive](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418888) in the Google Chrome XSS Auditor concerning a textarea with some js-ish text, for example `action=""`:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'https://www.dokuwiki.org/sandbox:chrome_xss_auditor?do=edit' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

The error message indicates that it could be resolved with either an `X-XSS-Protection`-header or an `Content-Security-Policy`-header. Indeed [a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016960/chromiums-xss-auditor-refused-to-execute-a-script) suggests deactivating XSS-Protection with `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");`.

However I feel somewhat uneasy about simply deactivating that XSS-Protection and tried to handle this problem using a `Content-Security-Policy`-header:

```
header('Content-Security-Policy: script-src * \'unsafe-inline\' \'unsafe-eval\'');
```

But unfortunately that did not affect the problem.

My question is: **Why did it fail and how can I use a `Content-Security-Policy`-header to handle the issue without deactivating XSS-Protection completely?**

PS: for reference see also https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/issues/1182

Comment: You can do some goofy stuff like base64 encode the data before sending it, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why did it fail and how can I use a Content-Security-Policy-header to
>   handle the issue without deactivating XSS-Protection completely?

It didn't work because you are allowing `unsafe-inline`.

Explicitly allowing unsafe inline is worse than disabling XSS protection via `X-XSS-Protection` because stored XSS attacks are possible with the former (in comparison to a locked down CSP), whereas the latter has no affect on them.

Workarounds - implement a secure CSP by disallowing the `unsafe` directives or disable XSS protection completely, as per the linked post.

The former is the more desirable option, however you may need to reengineer your page or site depending on whether you've used inline JavaScript or not. If you move all your JS to external files, this would make this possible and you would have a more secure system as a result.