# Parts of a string disappear on submit

Tags: php, html

I have following problem:

I generate a string like this in my code:

```
$str = '<span class="span" id="span1" onclick="edit(1);">123</span>
        <span class="span" id="span2" onclick="edit(2);">123</span>
        <span class="span" id="span3" onclick="edit(3);">123</span>
        <span class="span" id="span4" onclick="edit(4);">123</span>';
```

and insert it into my database on submit. The string output is on the same page.
If I just load the page everything works fine. But after submitting and refreshing the page the output of the string looks like that in my HTML code:

```
<span class="span" id="span1" onclick>123</span>
<span class="span" id="span2" onclick>123</span>
<span class="span" id="span3" onclick>123</span>
<span class="span" id="span4" onclick>123</span>
```

and I get following warning/error in my console:

```
(4)The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://www.foo.com/path_to_file/' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.
```

The number in the front is always the amount of the spans I have.

**EDIT**

I ran the code on Firefox ( I used Chrome before) and everything works as it should and I dont have no errors at all.

Comment: Nice. Where are you generating this code? How are you executing it? What is the server being used? Are you doing this in an online service or something?

Comment: The code is generated in javascript. I have an insert textarea and on buttonclick the inserted text gets added to the string. The string is in a hidden input field and gets submitted with a regular submit button, so I can insert it into my database. The script runs on a webspace I have.

Comment: It's a chrome & safari feature, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017013/4262684) if you only want to disable it.