# jquery works in Firefox, Edge, but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have the following code that works in Firefox, Edge, but not in Chrome.

```
            <script>
            function hst_collected() {
            var value = $( 'input[name=interpret_hst_collected]:checked' ).val();
            if (value == 1) {
               $('#recording2').hide();
               $('#recording3').hide();
            }
            if (value ==2) {
               $('#recording2').show();
               $('#recording3').hide();
            }
            if (value ==3) {
              $('#recording2').show();
              $('#recording3').show();
            }
            }
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                hst_collected();
            });

            $('input[name=interpret_hst_collected]').change(function(){
                hst_collected();
            });
            </script>
```

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try to provide us with a minimum working example?

Comment: What exactly not working? `hst_collected();` on document ready ?? OR `hst_collected();` on change event? OR both doesn't work?

Comment: You need to specify the context of your question; what elements do you have on your page? What is the expected behavior and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code and modify your code (suppose you are using the radio button):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    function hst_collected() {
        var value = $('input[name="interpret_hst_collected"]:checked').val();
        if (value == 1) {
            $('#recording2').hide();
            $('#recording3').hide();
        }
        if (value == 2) {
            $('#recording2').show();
            $('#recording3').hide();
        }
        if (value == 3) {
            $('#recording2').show();
            $('#recording3').show();
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hst_collected();
        $('input[name="interpret_hst_collected"]').change(function () {
            hst_collected();
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="interpret_hst_collected" value="1" />Level I
    <input type="radio" name="interpret_hst_collected" value="2"/>Level II
    <input type="radio" name="interpret_hst_collected" value="3"/>Level III

    <div id="recording2" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:antiquewhite">
        a
    </div>
    <div id="recording3" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:aqua">
        b
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this (using Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 and Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I found a solution in this post: [Chromium's XSS auditor refused to execute a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016960/chromiums-xss-auditor-refused-to-execute-a-script).

I need to bypass Chrome's XSS protection. It's working now.

Thanks.